# changing a member of an ENUM vs. adding a member

Tags: mysql, enums

When I change an existing member of an ENUM the query takes quite a while, whereas adding a member takes almost no time at all. Why is this? If anything I'd have expected it to be the other way around.

In thinking about how ENUM might be implemented...  it seems like an ENUM might be, internally, a TINYINT or something, with numeric values mapped to strings. With an implementation like that presumably neither would take too much time. Unless maybe you were adding a new element that forced ENUM to go from TINYINT to INT or whatever.

But I guess that's not how it's implemented...

Comment: Give us some examples that show the behaviour. NB emums are stored as strings. Never been a big fan of this feature personally.

Comment: The slow down is proportionate to the number of rows in the table. It's noticable with 700,000 rows but not so much with one or two rows. As such my ability to provide a demo with, say, sqlfiddle.com, is limited.

Comment: Just meant the current Enum, and the alter table statement. Becaue they are strings in the db I suspect a Change From EA, EB gto EA, EC, would result in a Update set enumcolumn = 'EC' Where EnumColumn = 'EB'...